# Lotus Java agent can unable to write on a network drive

Tags: lotus-domino, javaagents

#### The problem to fix

I have a java agent in a database on a Lotus Domino 8.5.3 server, to create export data on a network drive. The signer of the agent is listed in all of the programmability restrictions fields of the server document. The windows user name of the server is added the folder with all access, except "Full access" and "Special rights". The agent can not create the file on the network drive, but can create the file on the local drive.

#### The error message (Domino server log)

```
2013.01.15 09:32:42   AMgr: Agent ('excelExport|excelExport' in 'Applications\ExcelJavaExport\ExcelJavaExport.nsf') printing: NotersMain: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key file_operation_not_allowed
2013.01.15 09:32:42   AMgr: Agent ('excelExport|excelExport' in 'Applications\ExcelJavaExport\ExcelJavaExport.nsf') error message: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key file_operation_not_allowed
2013.01.15 09:32:42   AMgr: Agent ('excelExport|excelExport' in 'Applications\ExcelJavaExport\ExcelJavaExport.nsf') error message:  at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:407)
2013.01.15 09:32:42   AMgr: Agent ('excelExport|excelExport' in 'Applications\ExcelJavaExport\ExcelJavaExport.nsf') error message:  at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:421)
2013.01.15 09:32:42   AMgr: Agent ('excelExport|excelExport' in 'Applications\ExcelJavaExport\ExcelJavaExport.nsf') error message:  at lotus.notes.JavaString.getFormattedString(Unknown Source)
2013.01.15 09:32:42   AMgr: Agent ('excelExport|excelExport' in 'Applications\ExcelJavaExport\ExcelJavaExport.nsf') error message:  at lotus.notes.AgentSecurityManager.checkWrite(Unknown Source)
2013.01.15 09:32:42   AMgr: Agent ('excelExport|excelExport' in 'Applications\ExcelJavaExport\ExcelJavaExport.nsf') error message:  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:180)
2013.01.15 09:32:42   AMgr: Agent ('excelExport|excelExport' in 'Applications\ExcelJavaExport\ExcelJavaExport.nsf') error message:  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:81)
2013.01.15 09:32:42   AMgr: Agent ('excelExport|excelExport' in 'Applications\ExcelJavaExport\ExcelJavaExport.nsf') error message:  at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:57)
2013.01.15 09:32:42   AMgr: Agent ('excelExport|excelExport' in 'Applications\ExcelJavaExport\ExcelJavaExport.nsf') error message:  at ExportDocumentFilteredFields.export(Unknown Source)
2013.01.15 09:32:42   AMgr: Agent ('excelExport|excelExport' in 'Applications\ExcelJavaExport\ExcelJavaExport.nsf') error message:  at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
2013.01.15 09:32:42   AMgr: Agent ('excelExport|excelExport' in 'Applications\ExcelJavaExport\ExcelJavaExport.nsf') error message:  at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
2013.01.15 09:32:42   AMgr: Agent ('excelExport|excelExport' in 'Applications\ExcelJavaExport\ExcelJavaExport.nsf') error message:  at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

#### Question

What can cause this problem, and how to fix that?

Comment: Set your agents security level to 2 or 3.

Comment: @SimonODoherty If it can create the file on local drive (which I understood refers to server local drive) I believe that is not the issue.

Comment: How are you running the agent? Scheduled, with URL or with Notes client?

Comment: @PanuHaaramo the agent run manually from agent list and scheduled as well.

Comment: And in both cases it creates the file on server? It's also a good idea to check what Simon suggested although that does not sound like a likely cause to me.

Comment: Don't want to do a full answer as not enough to go on. But writing to network drives is generally messy as you need the running process to have access to the Drive. So if you have access, but Domino server is running under the system account it won't have access (unless you gave the system account access).

Comment: One workaround for this is for the agent to use FTP instead of filesystem access in order to create the file.  Of course, the customer will have to enable an FTP service at the intended destination.

Answer (score 3):

Finally we found the solution to implement writing on a network drive from a Lotus Java Agent:

1. Use **[Microsoft Windows UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention)** for path instead of mapping name
2. Check the **Windows User Name** of the Domino server using **task manager**
3. Add the proper rights to the Windows user Name of the Domino server to the
   folder